# How to manage Messenger component memory in Symfony 5.3

Tags: php, symfony, rabbitmq, amqp

I use for my project in Symfony 5.3, the [Messenger Component](https://symfony.com/doc/5.3/components/messenger.html) with a RabittMQ server. I want to manage my memory of my MessageHandler because my code is taking too much memory (`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 33554440 bytes`).

For each message consumed, I feel like the `MessageHandler` retains the memory of the previous `MessageHandler`. This is my class where I run a command:

```
class MessageHandler implements MessageHandlerInterface
{

    private KernelInterface $kernel;

    public function __construct(KernelInterface $kernel)
    {
        $this->kernel = $kernel;
    }

    /**
     * @param RequestMessage $requestMessage
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function __invoke(RequestMessage $requestMessage)
    {
        $application = new Application($this->kernel);
        $application->setAutoExit(false);

        $input = new ArrayInput([
            'command' => 'app:my-command',
            'userId' => $requestMessage->getUserId(),
            '--no-debug' => ''
        ]);


        $output = new BufferedOutput();
        $application->run($input, $output);
    }
}
```

And I consume my messages with this command:

```
$ php bin/console messenger:consume -vv
```

I am looking for a solution to consume each of my messages with an independent memory. I don't know where the problem is, if someone can help me.

I can think of a memory leak but I don't understand why the memory of a message is not cleaned.

Comment: is this after one message? Then it's the code, not the messenger

Comment: Your message handler runs a command line command? Why would you do that? Seems a weird design.

Comment: No, this error appears after n messages, when the memory is too large. @Martijn

Comment: And I use a command because I also need to access this functionality by terminal. @yivi

Comment: Still, it doesn't make sense. If you need this both from CLI and through Messenger (or Web, or whatever), encapsulate the funcionality in a service, that you call either in the Command, or the Message Handler, or the Controller, etc.

Comment: The better solution would be to create an ExampleService, with a ExampleService->foo(), which you both use in a message and in the command. Will simplify your code and maintainability.

Comment: Indeed, I will modify that, this might solve my problem. Thank you @yivi

Comment: Yes, I will do that @Martijn, thank you.

Comment: Mind you: that will just be good for the programmer. The code wont care about it :)

Comment: Sure, but I have a chance that the command has poor memory management or something. In any case, it's a good way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I am aware that I have a memory issue but I have to find a solution.

To run my command, I use Symfony's [Process](https://symfony.com/doc/5.3/components/process.html) component to run my command in a different process to not overload RAM and run it independently. This is my resolve code:

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

$completedCommand = 'php bin/console app:my-command ' . $user->getId() . ' --no-debug';
$process = Process::fromShellCommandline($completedCommand);
$process->run();

if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
    // Example: Throw an exception...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> #### Deploying to Production
>
> On production, there are a few important things to think about:
>
> **Don't Let Workers Run Forever**
> Some services (like Doctrine's EntityManager) will consume more memory over time. So, instead of allowing your worker to run forever, use a flag like messenger:consume --limit=10 to tell your worker to only handle 10 messages before exiting (then Supervisor will create a new process). There are also other options like --memory-limit=128M and --time-limit=3600.

From: [Symfony Messenger Docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#deploying-to-production)

Comment: Yes but I think it's not a problem of time, I consume all the messages in a minute, but I will try to do that in a service as you told me.

Comment: That suggestion isnt about time, its about the amount of messages :)

Comment: In this case, I have only 6 messages :/